# android how to run more than one instance of emulators with ip addresses

Tags: android, android-emulator

I use [pawserver](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/) tool with my app and have issue to test it because pawserver tool give me same IP Address (10.0.2.15) for all instance of emulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

As it is based on VirtualBox, you will be able to set one IP address per instance.

Comment: I will test Genymotion tool, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: GREAT REFERENCE, Thank you very much, I test it and it's useful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The docs actually contain information about doing what you want to do.

Check the section titled "Using Network Redirection" which states:

```
To communicate with an emulator instance behind its virtual router, you need to set up network redirection on the virtual router. Clients can then connect to a specified guest port on the router, while the router directs traffic to/from that port to the emulated device's host port.
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to change the emulator of port but it doesn't work with my app, So I want to have one IP Address for each emulator.